# React unit testing, checking if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, chai

I am trying to build some unit tests for my react code using chai. I seem to be having some trouble targeting and checking if a checkbox is checked and am unsure why. I have tried 2 methods so far :

The first is this :

```
let Element;

describe('Search Filters Filter Component', () => {
  beforeEach(function() {
    Element = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<searchFiltersFilterComponent filterGroup={filterGroup} filter={filter} />);
});

it('renders the search-filters-filter component', () => {
    expect(Element).not.to.be.undefined();
});

 it('is checked when provided with correct object', () => {
    const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(Element);
    const input = domNode.querySelector('input');
    console.log("checkbox?", input);
    //expect(element(input.isSelected()).to.be.true();
});

});
```

Right now this is not working, the input is logging as null. The second method I tried was this :

```
it('is checked when provided with correct object', () => {

    const CheckBox = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(Element, 'singleFiltersFilterInput');
    console.log("checkbox?", CheckBox);
    //expect(element(by.model(el)).isSelected()).to.be.true();
});
```

And this one is giving me an error of : `Invariant Violation: findAllInRenderedTree(...): instance must be a composite component`

I am stumped as to how to target and check if the checkbox is checked properly, I was going to just say `expect(element(input.isSelected()).to.be.true();`, however I cannot seem to target the checkbox on the test render properly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

*Update* :

so it seems that capitalizing the `SearchFiltersFilterComponent` was one of my issues, one i fixed that, I can now see the component correctly using  :

```
  const CheckBox = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(Element, 'singleFiltersFilterInput');
  console.log("checkbox?", CheckBox);
  expect(CheckBox.is.selected()).to.be.true();
```

However, that assertion is not correct. So I am wondering what the correct way to see assert that the checkedbox is checked is? I can see in the log it has a `_checkness` value, so I could do `CheckBox._checkness`, but i would prefer if there was an assertion that did this instead. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried? 
`expect(CheckBox.checked).to.be.true();`

Comment: What is "searchFiltersFilterComponent"?